# 3 monitors connected, but 2 are active, the 3rd monitor is forced inactive

Tags: drivers, display, hdmi, displayport, intel-graphics

When I'm trying to use 3 monitors, 2 are active and the third monitor is forced inactive, I've already tried updating the graphics driver, reducing the resolution of the active display, using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to set it to extend, and none of that worked.

When I try to configure the display extension directly from Start -> Settings -> System -> Display, I get the error “Failed to save display settings. Try a different combination of these settings."

I dual-boot with Linux that perfectly supports triple monitors with no problems, which leads me to believe it's a software lock in Windows, I want to know how to get around this software lock.

My processor:
https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/64899/intel-core-i7-3610qm-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-30-ghz.html

And from Intel info:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025673/graphics.html

- **System Model**: HP ENVY 17 Notebook PC
- **CPU**: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3610QM
- **iGPU**: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000

  - **Driver Model**: WDDM 1.3
- **dGPU**: AMD Radeon HD 7800M Series

  - **Driver Model**: WDDM 2.0
- **1st monitor**: HP M27fe FHD 1920x1080 - DisplayPort => HDMI
- **2nd monitor**: HP 24f 1920x1080 - HDMI => HDMI
- **3rd monitor**: built-in laptop monitor 1920x1080
- **Drivers**:

  - **For Intel**: I used all the latest and previous drivers that I found in the Internet;
  - **For AMD**: I used both the latest and the oldest drivers for Windows, as well as intermediate versions of the drivers.

On the laptop itself, I have 2x DysplayPorts and 1x HDMI port.

As for the BIOS, I don't have any video card settings either. It looks like here:https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/using-3-monitors-simultaneously-problems-in-the/1ef22a6b-ed4d-4fb6-831b-d71ed46fe760